# Creating a clone page for overflow content (Similar to Microsoft Word)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**objective:**

I'm trying to make a preview of what the printed outcome of a sortable list would look like within a webpage.

**Goal of The Code:**

The code below makes a clone of the first "page" that is created when the height of the sortable list matches the height of its parent container, this can be achieved by adding more sortable objects by dragging them over by the first list.

**Problem:**

The desired outcome works for the first recreation of the "page", but when more sortable objects are dragged over the code continues to make clones of the "page".

```js
$(function() {



$(".draggableobject").draggable({

stop: function(){
if ($(".sortnewdiv").height() == $("#Container").height()){
   $('#Container').clone().find('.sortable li').remove().end().appendTo("#sidearea");
   
$("#Container").removeClass("sortnewdiv");
}
},
connectToSortable: ".sortable"
});



$(".sortable").sortable({ 
cancel: 'input,textarea,button,select,option,[contenteditable]'
});

    
    
    
});
```

```css
#Button{
 margin-bottom:1%;
}

#firstContainer{
background-color: white;
height:160px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #000;
overflow: hidden;
width: 45%;
float: left;
}

#Container{
background-color: white;
height:200px;
margin-bottom: 5%;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #000;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}

.draggableobject{
 height: 40px;
}

.editable{
width: 75%;
height: 100%;
float:left;
}

.move{
width:25%;
height: 100%;
float:left;
background-color: black;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px grey;
}



#sidearea{
width: 45%;
float: left;
margin-left: 10%;
}


ul {
height: 100%;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}


.sortable li{
height: 40px;
background-color: grey;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="parentdiv">

 <div id="firstContainer">
 <ul id="draggable">
 <li class="draggableobject">5</li>
 <li class="draggableobject">6</li>
 <li class="draggableobject">7</li>
 <li class="draggableobject">8</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="sidearea">
 <div id="Container" class="first sortnewdiv">
 <ul class="sortable">
 <li><div class="editable" contentEditable = "true">1</div><div class="move"></div></li>
 <li><div class="editable" contentEditable = "true">2</div><div class="move"></div></li>
 <li><div class="editable" contentEditable = "true">3</div><div class="move"></div></li>
 <li><div class="editable" contentEditable = "true">4</div><div class="move"></div></li>
 </ul>
 </div>



</div>
```

Comment: I added an objective because I'm open to exploring different solutions for the desired outcome. To better clarify the desired outcome I am looking to achieve the same function that a Microsoft Word project does, which when there is overflow then a new page is created and the overflow is appended to the new page.

Comment: Does the sortable objects all have the same height ?

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I used a different approach. I made a function `adjust_pages()` that is called every time we sort or drag an element. So basically you can call it every time the content of the pages is changed. This function loop through every page, and reposition the elements according to the behavior you are looking for (like Microsoft Word). It will also remove or add pages when needed. See the comments in the function to see how i did.

```js
$(function() {
    make_sortable();
    make_draggable();
});
function make_sortable(){
    $(".sortable").sortable({ 
        connectWith: ['.sortable'],
        stop: function(){
            adjust_pages();
        },
        cancel: 'input,textarea,button,select,option,[contenteditable]'
    });
}
function make_draggable(){
    $(".draggableobject").draggable({
        stop: function(){
            if($('#draggable > li').length == 0){
                $('#draggable').append('<li style="height:'+(30+Math.random()*80)+'px;" class="draggableobject">'+$('li').length+'</li>');
                $('#draggable').append('<li style="height:'+(30+Math.random()*80)+'px;" class="draggableobject">'+$('li').length+'</li>');
                $('#draggable').append('<li style="height:'+(30+Math.random()*80)+'px;" class="draggableobject">'+$('li').length+'</li>');
                make_draggable();
            }
            adjust_pages();
        },
        connectToSortable: ".sortable"
    });
}
function adjust_pages(){
    $('.page').each(function(i,e){
        // while{ the first element of this page fits in the previous page, send it to the previous page} 
        if(i > 0){
            while($($('.page > ul')[i]).find('li').length > 0 && $($('.page')[i-1]).height()-$($('.page > ul')[i-1]).height() >= $($($('.page > ul')[i]).find('li')[0]).height()){
                $($($('.page > ul')[i]).find('li')[0]).appendTo($('.page > ul')[i-1]);
            }
        }
        // if the current page is empty, delete it, and start over
        if($($('.page > ul')[i]).find('li').length == 0){
            $(e).remove();
            adjust_pages();
            return false;
        }
        // while{ there is too much element in this page, send the last element to the next page } 
        while($($('.page > ul')[i]).height() > $(e).height()){
            if($('.page')[i+1]){
                $($('.page > ul')[i]).find('li').last().prependTo($('.page > ul')[i+1]);
            }
            else{
                // need a new page, add an empty page, and start over
                $('#sidearea').append('<div class="page"><ul class="sortable ui-sortable"></ul></div>');
                make_sortable();
                adjust_pages();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```css
#Button{
    margin-bottom:1%;
}
#firstContainer{
    height:100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.draggableobject{
    height: 40px;
}
#sidearea{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.page{
    float:left;
    background-color: white;
    height:280px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li{
    background-color: grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #000;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="firstContainer">
    <ul id="draggable">
        <li class="draggableobject">5</li>
        <li class="draggableobject">6</li>
        <li class="draggableobject">7</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="sidearea">
    <div class="page">
        <ul class="sortable">
            <li contentEditable="true">0</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I really enjoyed how you added different size divs to prove the function of the code.

Comment: Happy to hear that ! I enjoyed coding it as well :)

Comment: There is one problem from the question that wasn't addressed in your answer (it was my fault, it's an inferred question) which is that the < li > tags are contentEditable which mean I'll have to detect when the text makes the div to large for the page.

Comment: And when you detect that, what do you want to do ?

Comment: what if we put a max-width on the <li>, then if the text is to long, the <li> will simply have more than one line ?

Comment: Since the code already support elements with different height, the rest will work as expected... Could this work with your context ?

Comment: I figured out what I can do. I'm going to take a part of my code and add it to your code so if sortable.height() == page.height() then adjust_page()

Comment: that way adjust_page() can be run without using sortable

Comment: Alright, so that actually didn't work as I wanted it to..... I'm going to edit your code so you can see the problem that I'm running into, and maybe you might have a suggestion to it. So when you run the edited code just hold down the "F" key in the "0" < li > tag and you'll see that the elements aren't resizing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196178/discussion-between-stephans-and-francois-huppe).